# TypeError: Cannot read property when using redux with functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert a class component which uses reducer and redux into functional component.
The functional component is giving me error. This is the class component for login page:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import classnames from "classnames";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // If logged in and user navigates to Login page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }} className="row">
          <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
           
            <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
              <h4>
                <b>Login</b>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  error={errors.email}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.email || errors.emailnotfound
                  })}
                />
similar fields for email, password and button...
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loginUser }
)(Login);
```

This is the reducer:

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "../actions/types";

const isEmpty = require("is-empty");

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I have made the following changes:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  });
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [props.auth]);
```

I get the following error when I try to tun it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined
useEffect(() => {
  36 |    // Update the document title using the browser API
> 37 |    if (props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
     | ^  38 |      props.history.push("/dashboard");
  39 |    }
  40 |  });
```

I think the reducer state is not being read here. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: According to error `props.auth` is not defined so it is not able to find isAuthenticated.

Comment: I dont see your full code did you pass props into the child ?

Comment: I did this:
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    };

    props.loginUser(userData);
  };
But I am trying to figure out how to convert the logic of this for my hooks functional component:
`
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loginUser }
)(Login);
`